# Get tag a id inside listitem id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I'm quite to new to JQueryMobile, JavaScript and HTML. In my screen I have a list of elements that are creates dynamically and when you click on each element it should get you to another screen depending on the name of the list item you clicked.

I have tried to get the a tag id, value, name... but it doesn't work... here is my code for each line:

```
<li style='height:30px;' id='$object'>
    <a class='resume' id='$object' href='javascript:loadGraph(this);'>
        <span class='name' style='font-size:10pt;height:5px;' value='$object'>$object </span>
        <span class='data' style='background:$alarmColor;font-size:10pt;color:$alarmText;height:15px;'>$debitPrevMax</span>
    </a>
    <a class='info' id='$object' href='javascript:threshold(this)'>Alarm Info</a>
</li>
```

The list have split buttons.

Comment: Can you define _doesn't work_?

Comment: You can't have duplicate IDs on a page. Also, it isn't valid for an ID to start with `$`, unless you're only supporting HTML5.

Comment: I'm only supporting HTML5. When I tried to access to element.id I get undefined

Comment: Are you using PHP to define these values? If so make sure to properly echo out the values.

Comment: This code is actually inside php. I create a string with this code that I will echo afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"When I tried to access to element.id I get undefined"*

When you do this...

```
href='javascript:threshold(this)'
```

...`this` is not a reference to the element. That's why the `id` is `undefined`.

You'd need to use `onclick=` instead.

```
onclick=':threshold(this)'
```

---

Also, as I stated in the comment above, *you can **not** have duplicated IDs on a page*. You'll likely only be able to fetch the first.

Even if you're not using them for DOM selection, it still isn't a good idea to have duplicates.

Comment: for the href use: href="javascript:void(0)"

Comment: Perfect!! If I change it for onClick it works perfectly!!! Thank you very much!! So quick answer, less than 3 minutes since I post it!

Comment: I can't yet!! Is too early!! but in five minutes I will!